# Columns in a wrong order when making a sparse matrix with `Matrix::sparseMatrix` [R]

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a data frame similar to the following:

```
sparsed <- 
structure(list(Movie = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8), User = c(32, 2, 56, 34, 
56, 89, 4, 2, 46, 89, 67, 56, 12, 35, 89, 2, 90, 12, 5, 78, 69, 
32, 64, 56, 2), Rating = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L
)), .Names = c("Movie", "User", "Rating"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")
```

What is the logic used to place values into a sparse matrix? In order to get it into a sparse matrix of the right dimension (8 x 15) I have to do the following odd conversions, otherwise it comes out as 8 x 90.

```
library(Matrix)    
sparsed$Movie <- as.factor(as.character(sparsed$Movie))
sparsed$User <- as.factor(as.character(sparsed$User))

sparse <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(sparsed$Movie),
                       j = as.numeric(sparsed$User),
                       x = as.numeric(sparsed$Rating))

#8 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

#[1,] . 3 1 . . . . . 2 . . . . . .
#[2,] . . . 4 . . . . 5 . . . . 3 .
#[3,] . 3 . . . 2 4 . . . 2 . . 5 .
#[4,] 5 . . . . . . . 3 . . . . . .
#[5,] 5 3 . . 1 . . 4 . . . . 3 2 4
#[6,] . . 2 . . . . . . . . 3 . . .
#[7,] . . . . . . . . 1 2 . . . . .
#[8,] . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

I am now happy with the dimension But the matrix columns are NOT in the right order. For example, the first column corresponds to movie 12 not 2. The order of rows are correctly in numerical order. Can anyone explain this? Any good way to make columns in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sparseMatrix` did not do anything wrong.

Before you converting your `sparsed` columns eventually to factors, `Movie` and `User` are numeric, so 2 is 2, 12 is 12. `max(Movie)` is 8 and `max(User)` is 90, so you will get a 8 x 90 matrix.

Once you convert those columns into factors, are you aware of the factor levels?

```
levels(sparsed$Movie)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8"

levels(sparsed$User)
#[1] "12" "2"  "32" "34" "35" "4"  "46" "5"  "56" "64" "67" "69" "78" "89" "90"
```

Levels do not match numerical order, For example, 12 is ahead of 2. If you do `as.numeric` on those factors, the first level "12" will appear in the 1st matrix column, level "32" will appear in the 3rd column. If you want them to be in the right numerical order, control levels by using `factor` not `as.factor`:

```
## take your original `sparsed` data frame, where `User` is numeric
sparsed$User <- as.numeric(
                   factor(as.character(sparsed$User),
                          levels = sort(unique(sparsed$User)))
                   )
## no need to do anything with `Movie` at it's already contiguous numeric from 1
sparse <- sparseMatrix(i = sparsed$Movie,
                       j = sparsed$User,
                       x = sparsed$Rating)

#8 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                                  
#[1,] 3 . . . 1 . . . 2 . . . . . .
#[2,] . . . . . 4 . . 5 . . . . 3 .
#[3,] 3 2 . . . . . 4 . . 2 . . 5 .
#[4,] . . . 5 . . . . 3 . . . . . .
#[5,] 3 . 4 5 . . 1 . . . . . 3 2 4
#[6,] . . . . 2 . . . . . . 3 . . .
#[7,] . . . . . . . . 1 2 . . . . .
#[8,] 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```